# TypeError: unorderable types: Node() < Node()

Tags: python, search, tile

In Python, I am implementing the A* search algorithm for solving the Tile Problem.
I have the following Node class which holds the state as a tuple of tuple. For example the initial state is:

```
initial= ((7,2,4),(5,0,6),(8,3,1));#empty tile is marked with value 0
```

Below is the Node class,

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, pathCost=0, emptyTileI=1,emptyTileJ=1):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
        self.pathCost = pathCost
        self.emptyTileI=emptyTileI;#row index of empty tile
        self.emptyTileJ=emptyTileJ;#column index of empty tile
    def expand(self, problem):
        children=[];#empty list of children nodes initially.
        #after doing some work....
        return children #a list of Node objects, one for each successor states, parent of the created nodes is self
    def getState(self):
        return self.state;
    def getPathCost(self):
        return self.pathCost;
    def getParent(self):
        return self.parent;
```

I also have a TileProblem class which holds the heuristics that will be used by A* as the following,

```
## very generic Problem superclass, subclasses can overwrite the goal test and the constructor, and should also add a successors function
class Problem:
    def __init__(self, initial, goal=None):
        self.initial = initial
        self.goal = goal
    def goalTest(self, state):
        return state == self.goal

class TileProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self, initial, goal=None):
        self.initial = initial
        self.goal = goal
    #used in priority queue
    "(Uses Accumulated Manhattan Distance heuristic)"
    def fAMD(self,element):
        return self.g(element)+self.hAMD(element)
    "(Uses Number of Misplaced Tiles heuristic)"
    def fMT(self,element):
        return self.g(element)+self.hMT(element)

    #backward cost. #When this function is executed, the parent of the element has been already updated (by expand function in parent Node)
    def g(self,element):
        return element.pathCost
    #forward cost 
    "(Accumulated Manhattan Distance heuristic)"
    def hAMD(self,element):
        goalState=self.goal
        elementState=element.getState()
        "We will calculate the accumulated Manhattan distance between goal state and element state"
        accumulatedSum=0;
        for i,tgoal in enumerate(goalState):
            for j,vGoal in enumerate(tgoal):
                for m, tElement in enumerate(elementState):
                    for n, vElement in enumerate(tElement):
                        if vGoal==vElement:
                            accumulatedSum=accumulatedSum + abs(i-m)+abs(j-n);#Manhattan distance

        return accumulatedSum

    #forward cost 
    "(Number of Misplaced Tiles heuristic)"
    def hMT(self,element):
        goalState=self.goal
        elementState=element.getState()
        "We will calculate the number of misplaced tiles between goal state and element state"
        misplacedTileSum=0;
        for m, tElement in enumerate(elementState):
            for n, vElement in enumerate(tElement):
                if(vElement!=goalState[m][n]):
                    misplacedTileSum=misplacedTileSum+1;
        return misplacedTileSum;
```

The priority Queue Class as the following,

```
class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f ## save the function for later, when we apply it to incoming items (nodes)
        self.q = []#defaultdict(list)
        self.maximal_size=0
    def push(self, item):
        insort(self.q, (self.f(item), item))
        self.updateMaximalSize();
    def pop(self):
        return self.q.pop(0)[1]
    def empty(self):
        return self.q==[];
    def getMaximalSize(self):
        return self.maximal_size
    def updateMaximalSize(self):
        if(len(self.q)>self.maximal_size):
            self.maximal_size=len(self.q)
    def getF(self):
        return self.f;
   # def printQ(self):
    #    for t in self.q:
     #       print("("+repr(t[0])+","+repr(t[1].getState())+")");

    #returns the priority value of an element if it exists or None otherwise
    #Needed in A* to judge whether to push an element to the queue or not by comparing its current priority to the updated one
    def getPriorityValue(self,item):
        for e in self.q:
            if e[1].getState()==item.getState():
                return e[0];
        return None

    #updates the priority value of an element in the queue. Needed in A* to decrease the priority value of an element
    def updatePriorityValue(self,item):
        self.q = [(v,i) if (i.getState() != item.getState()) else (self.f(item),item) for (v, i) in self.q]
        self.updateMaximalSize();
```

my A* algorithm,

```
def aStarSearch(problem,frontier):
    closed=[];#explored set
    frontier.push(Node(problem.initial))
    print("In A* Search, Popping The Following Nodes (States) in-order:")
    while not frontier.empty():
        node=frontier.pop();
        print(node.getState()), #printing the history of popped nodes(states)
        closed.append(node.getState()); # add it to closed state to prevent processing it again
        if problem.goalTest(node.getState()): #if this is a goal node
            return node; #just return it
        children=node.expand(problem); #otherwise, lets expand it
        for c in children: #looping over the children
            if(c.getState() in closed): #already popped from the queue and closed
                continue; #ignore it
            priorityValue=frontier.getPriorityValue(c); #the child priority value in the queue
            if(priorityValue==None): #not in the queue
                frontier.push(c) #add it to the queue
            elif (frontier.getF(c) < priorityValue): #in the queue but this is a better path
                frontier.updatePriorityValue(c); #decrease the priority in the queue
        #frontier.printQ();        
    return None;
```

Finally, in my main,

```
initial= ((7,2,4),(5,0,6),(8,3,1));#empty tile is marked with value 0
goal=((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,0));

"A* Graph Search using Accumulated Manhattan Distance heuristic"
print("A* Graph Search using Accumulated Manhattan Distance heuristic:")
tileAStarSearch = TileProblem(initial,goal); 
frontier= PriorityQueue(tileAStarSearch.fAMD); #accumulated Manhattan distance heuristic
aStarResult=aStarSearch(tileAStarSearch, frontier);
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
    aStarResult=aStarSearch(tileAStarSearch, frontier);
  File "C:\Users\zjalmahmoud\workspace\Tile_Problem\search.py", line 211, in aStarSearch
    frontier.push(c) #add it to the queue
  File "C:\Users\zjalmahmoud\workspace\Tile_Problem\utilsSimple.py", line 61, in push
    insort(self.q, (self.f(item), item))
TypeError: unorderable types: Node() < Node()
```

I do not understand the cause of this problem. Why should the insort care about the items. I only expect it to push the item and sort by the "priority" value which is an integer in my case (the accumulated Manhattan Distance). How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe you have shown the code where your error happens; however, if you want your custom `Node` class to respond to logical comparison operators you have to [define the methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) to do that yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have nodes with equal priority in the queue. Python then tries to order the `(priority, node)` tuple by comparing the nodes. That's because tuples are compared in *lexicographical order*, just like you'd sort names. With two names, if the first letters match, you compare the second letter, etc, until you have different letters and can order those, comparing tuples works the same way. If the priorities match, the nodes are compared.

Either make your nodes orderable (you can use the [`functools.total_ordering()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) plus an `__eq__` and a `__lt__` method) or insert a counter value into the priority queue tuples to break the tie:

```
# at the top
from itertools import count

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f ## save the function for later, when we apply it to incoming items (nodes)
        self.q = []#defaultdict(list)
        self.maximal_size=0
        self._counter = count()
    def push(self, item):
        insort(self.q, (self.f(item), next(self._counter), item))
        self.updateMaximalSize()
```

and update the rest of the `PriorityQueue()` class to look for the item at index `2` (or better still, at index `-1`). Update the list comprehension in the `updatePriorityValue()` method to unpack the queue items to `(v, c, i)` and to include those again in the left-hand-side expression.

The counter (produced by [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)) inserts an ever increasing integer, so there will never be two tuples with `(priority, counter, item)` where both the priority and the counter are equal; thus the items are never compared.

This means that for equal priority, items that were inserted *later* win the tie. Use `-next(self._counter)` instead if you want items inserted *earlier* to win instead.

Comment: Thanks. That Makes sense. But can you show me how to do that in code?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this part "and update the rest of the PriorityQueue() class to look for the item at index 2 (or better still, at index -1)." What is in my mind now is to define a function count() which increases the counter value?

Comment: What does count return here? And what does next return?

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: `itertools.count()` returns an iterable that endlessly produces an ever-increasing number. The [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) simply retrieves the next number in the series.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: your class uses `return self.q.pop(0)[1]` to return the highest-priority item from the queue. You'll have to change that to `return self.q.pop(0)[2]`, or use `return self.q.pop(0)[-1]` to always return the last element of the tuples stored in the queue. Ditto in the `getPriorityValue()` (change `e[1]` to `e[-1]`), and you'll need to update the `updatePriorityValue` method to take the counter into account too.

Comment: okay Now I am getting new errors when popping: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getState'
I think I missed this part because I don't get it "and update the rest of the PriorityQueue() class to look for the item at index 2 (or better still, at index -1)."
You mean I should update the pop function? How?

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: do you understand how the queue stores things? Before my change it stored `(priority, item)` tuples. The code counts on that setup by accessing the elements of the tuple by index, or by unpacking the tuples in `updatePriorityValue()`). You'll need to update those methods to handle `(priority, count, item)` tuples instead.

Comment: Yes I got everything now. I did not pay attention earlier that i have to change the tuple indexing since it was updated, but now I realized that. Thanks alot

Comment: Nice idea with the counter. To use that idea with the vanilla `PriorityQueue` tho, what I did was multiply my priority constants e.g. use `PRIO1 = 0` then `PRIO2 = 1000000` etc. Now I can use simply `self.q.put_nowait((prio + next(self._counter), item))`.